# Is there an R function to calculate the variable importance in a keras RNN?

Tags: r, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I'm looking for a function to calculate the variable importance of a RNN in Keras, using layers such as LSTM or GRU that require a 3D array as input. I tried with `DALEX::feature_importance`, `ingredients::feature_importance`, `iml::FeatureImp`, `caret::varImp` but none of them works with 3D array input.

Is there any function for R to calculate the variable importance for a RNN in Keras?

Answer (score 1):

Implemented in https://github.com/ModelOriented/ingredients/pull/141 and waiting for feedback or merge. Hopefully, next version of ingredients::feature_importance will work with this kind of data

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).